# UIImagePickerController - Aligning an Image Guide to a Crop Area

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I'm using a UIImagePickerController with an overlay of a transparent white rimmed rectangle as a guide for capturing a small section of the view that the user would be interested in, centered in screen coordinates (320 x 480, portrait).

The problem is, I'm not entirely sure which bits of camera's view (actual photo) the viewfinder is showing, it can't be showing all of it because the image resolution is 3264 x 2448, which is a different width-length ratio to the screen space available, and it's showing fullscreen.

I need to be able to crop the exact image area that is "under" the overlay on the UIImagePickerController view from the actual produced image.

I've tried taking a ratio of the width of the sample divided by the width of the portrait camera view, and then multiplying the width of the image by that and scaling the y-coordinates from that, but the results are incorrect.

How could I try to solve this?